Is there a way to call method from an extended class in a interface default method?
I got like 10 classes that should implement an interface.
Those classes also extend a type of another class, either directly or as subextended class. I cannot change those classes i extend, because they are not from me.
interface IStuff 
{     
    default void doStuffInterface     
    {         
        // Call extended classes method and variable:        
        this.doStuffExtended(this.extendedVariable);     
    }     
    ... 
}  

class C1 
{     
    protected int extendedVariable;     
    protected void doStuffExtended(int var) { //do stuff }     
    ... 
}  

class C2 extends C1 
{    
     ... 
}

In my case, i got classes that extend either class C1 or class C2 and all of those should implement the interface.
How can i make sure that all of my classes have the same functionality of doStuffInterface, without having to write it specifically in each of those classes?
I thought about giving the default interface method an object of class C1, but that wouldnt work because the method and variable are protected.

this looks like a XY problem. why do you have to guarantee all your classes have "the same functionality of doStuffInterface"?

The functionality of the doStuffInterface method is basically a initializer method for the stuff that needs to be done to work with the interface.
The extend class C1 has a functionality of stateDefinitions. Those need to be registered before i can work on them. So i wanted a method that basically registers those stateDefinitions.

maybe you could split the classes, have 1 class that implements the interface and calls your other classes that do not implement this interface

Create a new interface and extend the already existing interface. Then, you can have a default method in the new interface. All of those classes can have the functionality of both interfaces plus a default method by implementing the new interface.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Use a base class to provide the needed functionality, C1 in your case. With java 17+ you can use sealed classes/interfaces to go a step further and allow a path of extension only through C1, making sure that every inheritor uses this basic initialization.
non-sealed class C1 implements IStuff {

  private int extendedVariable;

  @Override
  public final void doStuffInterface() {
    doStuffExtended();
    doStuffSuperExtended();
  }

  private void doStuffExtended() {
    System.out.println("default initialization - " + extendedVariable);
  }

  protected void doStuffSuperExtended() {
    //nothing by default
    //extra actions by inheritors, if required
  }
}

